# Honeypot Attribute creates syntax error in MVC 3 project

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I went to the following link and started performing the instructions step-by-step.

https://github.com/webadvanced/Honeypot-MVC/wiki/Simple-Getting-Started-Guide

I also added using SimpleHoneypot.Core; at the top of my controller.

I have the listed dll's, but when I try to add the Honeypot attribute to my Httppost method, I get a syntax error.

It says the type SimpleHoneypot.Core.Honeypot exists in both '...MVC2.dll' and '...MVC3.dll'. Previously, I tried to delete the MVC2.dll package, but then then Honeypot didn't appear to be recognized at all.

How do I use the Honeypot attribute in my controller?

Answer (score 0):

In the `References` folder in your solution, delete the reference to `SimpleHoneypot.NET4.MVC2`. Make sure the reference to `SimpleHoneypot.NET4.MVC3` is still there. Your application should now build.